# Next.JS Image `layout='fill'` is broken

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

When using the Next.js image component, the docs claim that: "When fill, the image will stretch both width and height to the dimensions of the parent element, usually paired with object-fit."

However, this is not what's happening. What it actually does is fill the image to take up the entire screen in a fixed position that doesn't respect scrolling. I've tried each `object-fit` value possible for the `img` and none has worked.

To reproduce, make a new next project and put an image in your public folder. Do this:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{width: '100px', height: '100px'}}>
        <Image src={"/i.png"} layout='fill'/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Image will take up the entire screen. You can try styling the `Image` component but I haven't found a way to make it work.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or why it's happening?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The wrapping div should have `position: relative`:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{width: '100px', height: '100px', position: 'relative'}}>
        <Image src={"/i.png"} layout='fill'/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is a consequence of how `position: absolute` works. It's containing block will be the nearest ancestor element that has any position value but `static` (the initial value).

Comment: thanks, I didn't see this, an obvious fix. Take my upvote, I will go to sleep now...

Answer (score 14):

You need to use `position: relative` for parent element.

Comment: But then it becomes overlapped with other elements.

Comment: you can use top and left and set them to pixels (0 for example) to align the element
style={{
                width: '100%',
                height: '764px',
                position: 'relative',
                left: '0px',
                top: '0px',
              }}

Comment: The trick to fix the overlapping issue is to put the image in its own div and give this wrapping div an explicit width and height. P.S. 100% width and height won't work. It has to be an absolute number.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using nextjs 13 then just use below:

```
<div className="relative rounded-md h-full p-3 border-2">
    <Image
        src={"../../../src.png"}
        width="0"
        height="0"
        sizes="100vw"
        className="w-full h-auto"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: `sizes` shouldn't always be 100vw. Read more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#sizes

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution it works fine with html2canvas

You need to use `style={{ position: "relative" }}` in the parent element to keep the same size

**`Solution 1:`**

In `className` add `h-auto` to automatically default image height to avoid distortion if you use Tailwind

```
            <div className="row1 " style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                <Image
                  className="imgs1 h-auto"
                  width="0"
                  height="0"
                  sizes="100vw"
                  src={imgstores ? imgstores : "/no-image.png"}
                  alt="Logo"
                  style={{ objectFit: "cover" }}
                />
            </div>
```

**`Solution 2:`**

Set `width={}` and `height={}` and style `height: "auto"`:

Even though I set the image height with `height={120}` it didn't understand so I had to add a style with `height: auto`

```
        <div className="row1 relative " style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                <Image
                  className="imgs1 "
                  width={120}
                  height={100}
                  src={imgstores ? imgstores : "/no-image.png"}
                  alt="Logo"
                  style={{ objectFit: "contain", height: "auto" }}
                />
              </div>
```